# Multiple Subviews inside a view and Autoresize

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to create a component that represent a logo using the code below:

```
- (void) createSubviews
{
    CGRect path[] = {
        CGRectMake(62.734375,-21.675000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(29.784375,-31.725000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(2.534375,-81.775000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(4.384375,-57.225000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(2.784375,62.875000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(4.334375,29.925000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(62.734375,2.525000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(29.784375,4.475000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(-21.665625,-81.775000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(-31.765625,-57.225000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(-81.615625,-21.425000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(-57.215625,-31.775000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(-81.615625,2.775000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(-57.215625,4.425000,27.400000,27.300000),
        CGRectMake(-21.415625,62.875000,18.900000,18.900000),
        CGRectMake(-31.765625,29.925000,27.400000,27.300000)};

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(path[i],
          CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.frame.size.width / 213.0,
                                     self.frame.size.height / 213.0));
        EllipseView * v = [[EllipseView alloc] initWithFrame:
                CGRectOffset(rect, self.frame.size.width/2.0, self.frame.size.height/2)];
        v.tag = 90000 + i;
        v.tintColor = self.tintColor;
        [self addSubview:v];
    }
    self.initialLenght = self.frame.size.width;
}

-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    CGFloat ratio = self.frame.size.width / self.initialLenght;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        EllipseView * v = (EllipseView*)[self viewWithTag:90000+i];
        v.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(ratio, ratio);
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time using the `CGAffineTransform` operations. Any hints on how to handle multiple subviews inside a view and keep them resizing as a group?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `UIView` reference:

> `transform` Property
>
> Specifies the transform applied to the receiver,
>   relative to the center of its bounds.

Note the "center of its bounds". The transform just scales the "content" of the `EllipseView`. Since the views are not moved in `layoutSubviews`, they remain at their position and only the dots are scaled.

Do you have to use transforms?

You might just change the frame of the views like you do in `createSubviews`.

As you already have the coordinates, you could create a `CAShapeLayer`, build a `UIBezierPath` with ellipses according to your `CGRect` array, add that layer as a sublayer to the main view and then scale that.